# Long-lasting or Long-standing

Tags: difference

My feeling so far is that "long-lasting" is more relevant when something that has a **non-homogeneous, "dynamic" nature** is distributed on the timeline, e.g. "long-lasting drop in sales", "long-lasting storm", etc. - sales volume drop may vary month over month, and so may intensity of the storm.

"Long-standing" in its turn, is more about the **"fixed" state/status** and is more relevant when we mention smth which dynamics is not essential (if present at all), e.g. "long-standing agreement" = **there was** an agreement, "long-standing belief" = **they believe**, etc.

Any comment on that please? ;-) Thank you guys!

Comment: Your analysis is in line with my immediate reaction, so I'd say you're on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Cambridge dictionary defines **"Long-lasting"** as *"continuing for a long period of time"* : e.g., *'a long-lasting friendship'*

It defines **"Long-standing"** as *"having existed for a long time"* : e.g., *'a long-standing agreement'*.

If someone has been a member of a committee for a long time, you could say :
*"He is a long-standing member of the committee"* [ NOT, *'a long-lasting member'*. It means he has survived longer than any other member of the committee.]

*"There is a long-standing agreement between them."* (The agreement has existed for a long period of time.)

*"All the damages were due to the long-lasting cyclone, Amphun."* (The cyclone continued for a long period of time.)

**"Long-lasting"** focuses on time and **"long-standing"** focuses on the durability or state of something over a long period of time.